# Python: .Rename & index - What is this doing?

Tags: python, pandas

new to Python, trying to work out what the following line is doing in Python any help would be greatly appreciated

`new = old.rename(index={element: (re.sub(' Equity', '', element)) for element in old.index.tolist()})`

Comment: That entirely depends on what `old` is.

Comment: Is removing the word 'Equity' from the strings of the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that source CSV file has the following content:

```
c1,c2
Abc,A,10
 Equity,B,20
Cex,C,30
Dim,D,40
```

If you run

```
old = pd.read_csv('input.csv', index_col=[0])
```

then *old* will have the following content:

```
        c1  c2
Abc      A  10
 Equity  B  20
Cex      C  30
Dim      D  40
```

Let's look at each part of your code.

`old.index.tolist()` contains: `['Abc', ' Equity', 'Cex', 'Dim']`.

When you run `{element: re.sub(' Equity', '', element) for element in old.index}`
(a dictionary comprehension), you will get:

```
{'Abc': 'Abc', ' Equity': '', 'Cex': 'Cex', 'Dim': 'Dim'}
```

so each value is equal to its key with one exception: The value for
`' Equity'` key is an empty string.

Note that neither *tolist()* not parentheses surrounding *re.sub(...)*
are not needed (the result is the same).

And the last step:

`new = old.rename(index=...)` changes the index in *old*,
substituting `' Equity'` with an empty string and the result is saved
under *new* variable.

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming old is pandas DataFrame, the code is renaming the index (see [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)) by removing the word Equity from each of the strings on it, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

old = pd.DataFrame(list(enumerate(['Some Equity', 'No Equity', 'foo', 'foobar'])), columns=['id', 'equity'])
old = old.set_index('equity')

print(old)
```

**Output** *(Before)*

```
             id
equity         
Some Equity   0
No Equity     1
foo           2
foobar        3
```

Then if you run:

```
new = old.rename(index={element: (re.sub(' Equity', '', element)) for element in old.index.tolist()})
```

**Output** *(After)*

```
        id
equity    
Some     0
No       1
foo      2
foobar   3
```

The following expression, is known as [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
{element: (re.sub(' Equity', '', element)) for element in old.index.tolist()}
```

for the data of the example above creates the following [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
{'Some Equity': 'Some', 'No Equity': 'No', 'foo': 'foo', 'foobar': 'foobar'}
```